# jQuery open facebox if the user is currently active on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, facebox

as we can use [facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) as popup.

i want to open this POPUP if user is not active for last 30 min on page.

and if user press close button or close the popup time will be restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you [ajaxpatterns.org/Timeout](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Timeout)